# How to centralize the text (on the homepage) when we expand the side navigation menu?

Tags: html, css

I am using a side navigation menu.When I expand the menu,the text on the screen shifts to right.I want the text on the screen to be in center,despite expanding the menu. Link to the code shared in comments

Comment: Please provide your HTML, CSS and JS code or you can try this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

Comment: please provide some code that you are using. Which can help us to help you

Comment: Please share that code...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/trm13zcv/

Answer (score -1):

Check the above solution, alter left and right margin accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.yourdiv
{
  margin-top: 55px;

  margin-left: 180px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>


 <div class="yourdiv">
<p id="text">Welcome to my homepage.Side navigation menu..</p>
</div>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("text").style.marginLeft="150px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("text").style.marginLeft="0px";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you that's what the problem is?

Comment: In some cases replacing <center> with margin:auto solves the problem, if it doesn't  i need to check the actual source code.

Comment: Ah, Ok. But maybe we should wait for OP to clarify his question.

Comment: there is some or the other error coming.posting my code.

Comment: store it in  jsfiddle.net and post url in comments.

Comment: I checked the code, I didn't get which text you wish to center. Could you specify it with clarity.

Comment: *Welcome to my homepage.Side navigation menu..*

Comment: When i click on *Open* the text *Welcome.....* should come in the center of the screen,rather then hidding.

Comment: I have edited the answer with solution, You can alter left and right margin similarly as per your preference.

Comment: I cannnot find the changes that i want..it is still the same.

Comment: No the text doesn't get covered by the menu http://jsfiddle.net/trm13zcv/3/ check if its the change you want?

Comment: "navigation menu" shifts to second line which should not happen. The entire line (as 1) should be in horizontal center.